# How can I get Tooltip to use a string variable as its parameter?

Tags: plotting, tooltip

I have an x/y data set casualties with Union and Confederate Civil War casualties.  I have a third variable, battles, listing the names of all of the battles.  Currently `Tooltip` will show the x/y pairs, but I want the name of the battle when I hover over a point.

```
casualtiesPlot = ListPlot[
  Tooltip[
   casualties], PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "Union vs. Confederate Casualties", 
  AxesLabel -> {"Union \n Deaths", "Confederate \n Deaths"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
casualties = {{100, 120}, {80, 70}, {150, 190}};

battles = {"Battle-1", "Battle-2", "Battle-3"};

tips = 
 MapThread[Tooltip, {casualties, Transpose[{battles, casualties}]}];

ListPlot[
 tips,
 PlotRange -> All,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotLabel -> "Union vs. Confederate Casualties",
 AxesLabel -> {"Union \n Deaths", "Confederate \n Deaths"}]
```

[image]

To show only the name of the battle:

```
tips = MapThread[Tooltip, {casualties, battles}];
```

If you want to use options, f.e.:

```
tips =
 MapThread[
  Tooltip[##,
    TooltipStyle -> {Background -> GrayLevel@0.9}] &,
  {casualties, battles}];
```